# Feature Coordinate Transform & Translate? "copy"

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

Using ArcGIS Pro, I have a 2D layer in California. The feature is a line-split-at-vertices w/ Z points.

I exported the feature to a .MAPX file and then imported into the Mt. Egmont (New Zealand) 3D tutorial.

How do I copy the feature from the imported California layer over to some location on Mt. Egmont?

I've been trying using copy/paste but keep getting "Paste Features failed".

Comment: You're likely to be outside your spatial references' domain.. California is in the northern hemisphere but Mt Egmont is in the southern hemisphere; domains can only go so far before you overflow a signed long int. Does the tutorial tell you to copy from California to New Zealand? If so I'd like to see the tutorial to understand what they're asking you to do.

Comment: No, the tutorial doesn't say anything like that so far.
I just need a 3D base map for some prototyping I'm doing. 
So my question remains: how do I copy the feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. It's solved.
I exported the feature to a tab delimited file and altered the coordinates manually ("translation").
I was wrong about the coordinate transformation.
Everything works fine in GCS_WGS_1984 ("WGS84").